# Turning a line in a table into a hyperlink

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, hyperlink, x3dom

I have this code which sets the values when clicked on the piece of text

```html
<transform scaleorientation="0,0,0,0" center="0,0,0" bboxsize="-1,-1,-1" bboxcenter="0,0,0"      render="true" scale="10 10 10" rotation="0,0,0,0" translation=" 0 0 0 " id="obj1">
<shape DEF1="Capstone" DEF2="2011" DEF3="Text1" DEF4="Capstone" DEF5="2011" DEF6="Text1"   DEF9="https://g3n1u5.com" DEF10="https://g3n1u5.com" Grouped="https://g3n1u5.com" Ungrouped="https://g3n1u5.com" kpi1="12266" kpi2="1120" kpi3="981" kpi4="1206" bboxsize="-1,-1,-1" bboxcenter="0,0,0" render="true" id="obj_1_shp"   >
<appearance>
<material diffuseColor='blue'></material>
</appearance>
<text string="group 1">
<fontstyle family="'SANS'" style="'BOLD'"></fontstyle>
</text>
</shape>
</transform>
```

I want to turn the following code to have a clickable hyperlink

```html
<div class="well" style="height: 50px; overflow: auto;">   
<table style="font-size:1em;">
<tr><td>Grouped: </td><td id="id_table3_Grouped">-</td></tr>
<tr><td>Ungrouped: </td><td id="id_table3_Ungrouped">-</td></tr>  
</table>
```

But no matter what I try, I can not get the value `id="id_table3_Grouped"` to be a hyperlink rather than just displayed when the text trigger is clicked on.

I tried all sorts of anchors and placements, but nothing worked.

What I expected was a working hyperlink in a table cell